# react redux - reset other state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am new in react redux.

i have implement like:

Store :

```
import { createStore } from "redux";

const initialState = {
    layersFlag : {
        baseDistrictADhabi: "none", 
        baseDistrictAAin: "none"
    }
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action)=>{
    switch (action.type) {
        case "layerChange":
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                ...state, 
                layersFlag : { 
                    baseDistrictADhabi: action.payload.baseDistrictADhabi,
                    baseDistrictAAin: action.payload.baseDistrictAAin
                }
            })
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const Store = createStore(reducer, initialState);

export default Store;
```

HomeScreen:

```
<Text> {this.props.baseDistrictADhabi} </Text>
<Text> {this.props.baseDistrictAAin} </Text> 

const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
    return {
        baseDistrictADhabi: state.layersFlag.baseDistrictADhabi, 
        baseDistrictAAin: state.layersFlag.baseDistrictAAin
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HomeScreen);
```

It is working but problem is when I am changing baseDistrictADhabi state then baseDistrictAAin(undefined) get reset.

Comment: What do you get if you console.log(action.payload) before 'switch (action.type)'?

Comment: ok wait i will take snapshot

Comment: I am getting {baseDistrictADhabi: "visible"}

Comment: So you should not set baseDistrictAAin

Comment: You don't need `Object.assign` AND `...state`, choose one or the other. Using the spread is easier, you can just `return { ...state, otherValues }`

Comment: can you add your answer. how manage more than 2. because i have many layersFlag.

Comment: You could use a ternary operator when assigning your payload in the store like this ```baseDistrictADhabi: action.payload.baseDistrictADhabi ? action.payload.baseDistrictADhabi : state.layersFlag.baseDistrictADhabi``` and do the same for ```baseDistrictAAin``` and your other layersFlag items. That will check if there's a value to assign, otherwise just assign the current state

Comment: I assume your action is just changing one value? so when you change baseDistrictADhabi, there is no baseDistrictAAin in your `action` ?

Comment: @Jono i have many layersflag.

Comment: I have many layersflag. suggest proper way to handle all

Comment: It would be better to have a separate action for each layerChange then, and a separate statement to assign the payload in your store. So something like ```layerChangeADhabi``` which only assigns ```baseDistrictADhabi```. Then do that for all your various layers

Comment: @Jamie-FenrirDigitalLtd answer is a better suggestion though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your action is only returning the value you want to update, you can just spread it into the layersFlag object.

Change your reducer to the following:

```
    case "layerChange":
        return {
            ...state, 
            layersFlag : {
                ...state.layersFlag,
                ...action.payload
            }
        }
```

This will keep all previous keys in your layersFlag object as they are, and only update the one that is returned in the action.